# Publish users using id from a different collection

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to access the userIds stored in a collection and then use them to publish the details of all of the meteor.users. My publish function doesn't isn't return anything?

```
Meteor.publish('allUsersWithOffers', function () {
  var user = Offers.find({}, {fields: {"UserId": 1}});

  return Meteor.users.find({_id: user});  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
Meteor.publish('allUsersWithOffers', function () {
  var offers = Offers.find({}, { fields: { UserId: 1 } }).fetch();
  var ids = _.pluck(offers, 'UserId');

  // This is critical - you must limit the fields returned from
  // the users collection! Update this as needed.
  options = { fields: { username: 1, emails: 1 } };
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: { $in: ids } }, options);
});
```

`find` returns a cursor - you need to call `fetch` to actually get the documents.

Comment: Nice. I'd recommend reading my [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) article - it addresses a couple of the issues encountered here.

Comment: I'll check it out.